# Requisição Ajax não funciona

Tags: php, ajax, json

Tenho 3 arquivos:

novaDose.php:

```
<label for="busca">Buscar cidadão:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="busca" placeholder="Digite parte do nome ou o CNS" onkeypress="busca(this.value);">
      <br/>
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">CNS</th>
            <th scope="col">Nome Completo</th>
            <th scope="col">Data de Nasc</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tabelaPaciente">
          <?php
            include 'conexao.php';
            $result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from paciente limit 20");

            while ($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
              $dataNasc = date_create($item["dataNasc"]);
              echo '<tr>
                      <td>'.$item["cns"].'</td>
                      <td>'.$item["nomePaciente"].'</td>
                      <td>'.date_format($dataNasc, "d/m/Y").'</td>
                    </tr>';
            }
          ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="novaDose.js"></script>
```

buscarPHP:

```
include 'conexao.php';

$result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from paciente");

echo json_encode($result);

mysqli_close($con);
```

novaDose.js:

```
function busca(){
$('#tabelaPaciente').empty(); //ATÉ AQUI FUNCIONA
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    dataType:'json',
    url:'buscar.php',
    success: function(dados){
    alert(dados); //ESSE ALERTA NÃO FUNCIONA
        for(var i=0;dados.length>i;i++){
            //Adicionando registros retornados na tabela
            $('#tabela').append('<tr><td>'+dados[i].cns+'</td><td>'+dados[i].nomePaAciente+'</td><td>'+dados[i].dataNasc+'</td></tr>');
        }
    }
});
};
```

Aparentemente tudo funciona ok, mas não consigo obter sucesso na requisição. Uso firefox e nos módulos de debug console e network não estão retornando nenhum erro.

Comment: se não funciona é porque não da success, inverte a linha do echo com a mysql close.

Comment: @JulioHenrique mesma coisa

Comment: coloca isso em cima do echo . header('Content-type: application/json');

Comment: @JulioHenrique ainda assim, sem retorno algum. veja que tenho um alert(dados) no campo success mas ele não chega a executar. como eu posso fazer pra mostrar algum erro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que falta um cabeçalho em seu buscar.php e o resultado precisa de fetch

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: application/json');

include 'conexao.php';

$result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from paciente");

echo json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Em seu código AJAX

```
 dataType:'json',
```

Isto significa a requisição está esperando um JSON como resposta, mas sem aquele cabeçalho no seu código php, o servidor vai responder um HTML.

O Jquery slim não contêm AJAX. Use o completo em:

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js

Comment: ainda assim, sem retorno algum. veja que tenho um alert(dados) no campo success mas ele não chega a executar. como eu posso fazer pra mostrar algum erro?

Comment: Tentaste aplicar     echo json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)); ?

Comment: se eu acessar direto o buscar.php os dados aparecem corretamente. mas ainda não está sendo listado na tabela

Comment: Em seu for, tente usar isto for(var i=0; i < Object.keys(dados).length  ;i++)

Comment: antes do for, tem um alert. e ele nem está sendo executado...

Comment: Se eu não me engano o jquery slim não tem ajax. Tenta usar o completo.

Comment: Era isso mesmo Luan. pode alterar sua pergunta pra ganhar os pontos. Salvou meu dia kkkkk

Comment: caramba, estranho é no console não mostrar erros ao usar ajax :/

Comment: Isso mesmo, não sei se desconfigurei algo, mas fica muito ruim de corrigir sem saber qual o erro :/